# Is it safe to protect the images only with a watermark image style?

Tags: 7, commerce, media

I'm building a website for selling stock photography and I'm looking for a way to protect the images. Here's what I'm using right now:

- [Imagecache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) to watermark photos
- Private file system for uploading all images
- The images are displayed on the front only through image styles with watermarking.

Question: is this enough and are there any ways users could bypass this (e.g. by directly trying to access certain image style)?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have other image styles, other than the ones you are watermarking?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, I will not use any of the other styles to display these images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not as secure as you would like it to be.
Basically if a user has access to view the image they can view any derivative image (image style), so long as they can work out the url to that derivative.

There is a module [image style access](https://drupal.org/project/image_style_access) that allows you to set up access rules per image style.

That should give you the extra protection you need.

Comment: Thanks Rooby, I will check out the module now and keep this thread posted.